# Get the HTML content when hitting URL in swift 3

Tags: swift, nsurl

My question is i want to hit the url and when i hit the url on server side the php return the results just `echo` in php and i have to save that result in variable in swift 3, i tried the below code:

```
let URLstr = URL(string: strURL)
let request = URLRequest(url: URLstr!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
print (request)
```

I didn't get the content of URL in swift which is much easier in objective C.

Comment: Look for `URLSession`. You created the request but didn't "fire it".

Comment: try to implement this with urlsession

Comment: The Objective-C version of the code you posted wouldn't work either. It's not easier in either language. It's the same APIs either way.

Comment: @Larme can you post the answer i am very thankful. i tried but they are not triggered the url . In info.plist i already add the AppSecurityProtocol to yes !

Comment: `request.httpMethod = "POST"` should be a GET

Comment: " can you post the answer i am very thankful": No there are plenty of question about that already. You didn't find one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the string initializer with the url.

```
do {
  let contents = try String(contentsOf: URLstr, encoding: .ascii)
} catch {
  // handle error
}
```

Or you can use URLSession.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLStr) { data, response, error in
   guard data != nil else { // no data }
   let contents = String(data: data!, encoding: .ascii)  
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: how to print the response, data and error ? it's work but i want to save the return content into the variable

Comment: I edited the answer. I assumed you wanted the html from the page.

Comment: Do not use this code. You should not load data from the Internet synchronously. You really should use `URLSession`.

Comment: @rmaddy why you said that, i get the content ... can you more specific why you said that not to use internet sync ... did you have better code for URLSession to get the htmlcontent ?

Comment: You can use the DispatchQueue and put it on a background thread.

Comment: @JeremiahJessel It's much better to use `URLSession`. You have far more control and can deal with errors.

Comment: @MohammadKalim There are countless examples of using `URLSession` to load data from a URL. A simple search will give you more than you could possible read.

Comment: @JeremiahJessel please can you tell me i got one error by using this:   let contents = try String(contentsOf: URLstr, encoding: .ascii) when there is space in the url like "example.com/index.php?a=hello world" then it's crash because of white space please let me know how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted the code provided above. To fetch HTML code use URLSession.

**Swift 5**

```
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let url = URL(string: "https://yourwebsiteaddress.com/")!
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        // Check whether data is not nil
        guard let loadedData = data else { return }
        // Load HTML code as string
        let contents = String(data: loadedData, encoding: .utf8)
        print(contents)
    }
    task.resume()
```